# How to update display-name in java maven project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

I have a J2EE webapp but when I try to update the display-name in web.xml maven install fails and I get.
  `[ERROR] <display-name> MUST NOT change between versions (was: abc xyz; now: abc-xyz).`
Is there anyway I can do this change?

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following plugin to change the display name

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>web.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>


    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Add property in pom.xml

```
<properties>
   <kp.version>1.0.0.1</kp.version>
</properties>
```

In web.xml display name add a placeholder as below

```
<display-name>KPWS-${kp.version}</display-name>
```